# Not receiving O365 Quarantine notification messages

Tags: office365, exchange-server

It seems that, for some reason, the O365 quarantine messages recently stopped going out, apparently to all of our users. I've looked in the quarantine and there are messages that have been quarantined for which we should have received notifications, but no such notifications have shown up in my or my users' mailboxes. I took a quick look at the settings and everything appears to be in order there (as far as I can tell - obviously I'm not a highly experienced Exchange admin):
[image: O365 Spam Notification Settings]
[image: O365 Spam Policy Settings]
I even went through my blocked senders/domains to make sure I hadn't somehow accidentally blocked the sender. The last notification received was 6 days ago (1/2/2020), but there has been plenty quarantined since then that should have triggered notifications. Nobody has made any changes to these settings in a couple of years, so there's no reason for this behavior to have changed. Is anyone else experiencing anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue appears to have resolved itself. As of Monday, all of our users started receiving the notifications again. The week+ of notifications that were missed are apparently lost to the electronic void, but at least they've started flowing again. I don't have an explanation or actual solution but here are some basic steps to take based on my own troubleshooting and the information in my [cross-post of this question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_security-mso_o365b/not-receiving-o365-quarantine-notification/535a2eab-20ac-4b65-abe7-a77ff8a3b6fa) on the Microsoft Community forums.

1. Check the user's other folders, including **Deleted Items** and **Junk Email**. It might be best to do a search through the entire **Inbox** and all subfolders.
2. Also, check the "*Recover Deleted Items*" option in the **Deleted Items** folder (There should be an option to "*Recover items recently removed from this folder*")
3. Check the quarantine (***O365 Security & Compliance --> Threat management --> Review***) to confirm that there are new messages for which notifications should be sent (*duh*).
4. Run a couple of message trace reports (***O365 Security & Compliance --> Mail flow --> Message trace***) from the "**Default queries**" section:

   - "**All failed messages for the last 7 days**" - The quarantine notifications may be going out but are not able to be delivered for some reason. This report may provide some insight if that is the case.
   - "**Messages pending delivery to users in my organization**" - It's possible that the quarantine notifications are simply stuck in the mail server's queue pending delivery.
   - "**All quarantined messages for the last 7 days**" - Look for newly quarantined messages, especially any from *quarantine@messaging.microsoft.com* (unlikely, but possible), and look at the details of one or more messages for any errors in the quarantine process. "Normal" quarantined messages should look something similar to this:
     [image: Spammy McSpamface]
5. Temporarily disable any additional spam filter policies you may have configured (***O365 Security & Compliance --> Threat management --> Policy --> Anti-spam***).
6. Temporarily disable the End-user spam notifications (***O365 Security & Compliance --> Threat management --> Policy --> Anti-spam --> [Spam filter policy in question] --> Configure end-user spam notifications***). Leave this disabled for a few hours before reenabling it.
7. If the notifications still don't work, try running a trace for quarantine notifications to a specific user

   - **Sender's Email Address:** quarantine@messaging.microsoft.com
   - **Recipient's Email Address:** <*user@domain.com*>
     That's as far as we got before the issue "magically" resolved itself. I'm posting these steps here in the hopes that one of them may be helpful in someone else's situation.